# Better than Switch case in powershel?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have an array like 5 system IDs for now like SID_1_name, SID_2_name......For each system ID .I need to add some details. So I have written powershell script of switch case .Which is working fine for now. But I wonder in future we may add more systems so that I need to add more cases which expands the script...Is there better way to do for future purpose aswell

```
    $excel=@()
    $list = Get-AznetworkInterface |where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -Clike '*$(givenVarible)'} |Select-Object
    foreach ($i in $list) {
   $x = " " | Select-Object SID1_name,SID1_VIP,SID2_name,SID2_VIP,SID3_name,SID3_VIP
   $case =1
   While ($case -1t $i.IpConfigurations.Count)
   {
   switch ($case){
   1 {
      $x.SID1_name = $i.IPconfigurations[$case];
     $x.SID1_VIP = $i.IPconfigurations[$case].PrivateIpaddress;
     break
     }
    2 {
     $x.SID2_name = $i.IPconfigurations[$case];
     $x.SID2_VIP = $i.IPconfigurations[$case].PrivateIpaddress;
     break
     }
    3 {
    $x.SID1_name = $i.IPconfigurations[$case];
     $x.SID1_VIP = $i.IPconfigurations[$case].PrivateIpaddress;
     break
     }
     $case =$case+1
     $excel +=$x
     $excel | Format-Table SID1_name,SID1_VIP,SID2_name,SID2_VIP,SID3_name,SID3_VIP
     $excel |Export-Csv -NTI - Path "$(Build.ArtifactoryStagingDirectory)/report.csv"
```

Comment: This code does not work at all. Please add a minimal working code example.

Comment: @Thomas could you create a chat room.I can explain in deail

Comment: You could create a PowerShell data file - `*.psd1` - and maintain your definitions as a [`hash table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) there; you can then load this hash table into your script using [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/import-powershelldatafile)

Comment: Please elaborate on _".For each system ID .I need to add some details."_ Do you mean you want extra properties to every system ID? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Theo @ mklement0 I have added details to my question.Please find and suggest